# Object mode vs edit mode shows diferent size UV map while render or material view

Tags: mesh, uv, uv-image-editor

i comed to this problem and nothing helped... i aplied scale of this object, i reunwraped that block again multiple times... i moved with points, recalculated normals, edge bevel, edge crease... shade flat, shade smooth.. subdivide.. do not know what to do with this wierd bug...

i even delete whole side and reface it... did the same thing...

would apreciated any advice

[image]

[image]

[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_tLLP6FlwgMolL6I6KLTnjAhyPWEzC7s/view?usp=sharing

***Update:*** had been playing around a bit... it is very strange combination of UV with fast Boolean. When i extrude it normali it is just lines... when i use diferent line and face edge it than it does this triangle.. XD when i unwrap than it gets corect in edit mode but in object mode it broke... becouse it apply that bolean...
[image]

---

After some testing i got an idea to join that bugy house object to new generated cube so that will get all basic properties of that cube (first select house than cube to have cube selected by light orange)

This did worked but if anyone have explain for this staf why it happend at the first place (it happend becouse of fast boolean + extrude but it is not normal to mess with UV - the house object in project is somehow setup badly or corupted) please let everyone know i have no idea.

Comment: Can you upload your project here? https://blend-exchange.com/ (remove unrelated objects, set "compressed" in settings)

Comment: maybe you have 2 version of your object overlapping?

Comment: do not have any overlaping i will upload tahat object on google disk... oh i found the issue while i was making projekt for you... boolean messed with it even while not toutching that objekt... i will still upload becouse i need that fast version of bolean.

becouse i am having house which i would like to animate halfcuting and axact type of bolean is slow and bugy...

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_tLLP6FlwgMolL6I6KLTnjAhyPWEzC7s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you actualy can not extrude any face in that object

Comment: You have a boolean modifier on your object, the stretched UV is where a cut was made by that modifier.

Comment: And that front is actualy only thing which i normaly extruded in that object long time ago... so any point made by extrude is corupted XD from what i learned in theese 20 mins... playing with it

Comment: how do you mean it markus ? when i remove that modifier and apply it back it is still broken. and it is not even toutching ... any object i set boolean on does this uv  think. 

Do not think this should be normal making this think with uv when it is extrued and boolean.

Comment: yep i just tested it... with normal cube and it works fine... there is something tricky bad with that house object.

Comment: haha i got an idea... you still can think why this does happend... but i moved on and had been doing something else... than i remembered how i repaired diferent bug by joining it to diferent object... and ofcourse... if you join that house to basic cube it will get repaired ;-) but i am still curious why had been bugy before...

Comment: Perhaps you're joining with something that replaces the "damaged" face (a face with stretched UV due to cutting) with a face that is properly UV unwrapped, therefore "repairing" it.